# How can I secure SPA and Azure Function with single Azure AD app registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

**Background**

I'm currently using Azure Functions v3.0 and MSAL Angular v2.0

I set up my Azure function AD registration using the express setup.

Callbacks were added automatically for function app, I've added a new one for the angular SPA.
Only id token flow enabled.

The SPA logs in successfully, and acquires a JWT Bearer token

Directly accessing the function app also results in a correct login, and returns a session cookie

**Question**

The difficulty arises in trying to get the function app to accept the bearer token from the SPA app, should this be possible, or do I need to somehow exchange the bearer token for a session token

Comment: There's quite some documentation on that available. It's a bit old, but you could have a look at [Securing a REST API with Azure Active Directory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kxE2QqtkMc).

Comment: It should accept the bearer token as long as it is an access token that you acquired using a scope that you defined in the app registration's Expose an API tab.

Comment: @rickvdbosch saw that video. There's a lot of documentation on older versions of functions,AD, msal, and using the implicit flow. very little on the newer flows.

also lots of differences in configs (default audience config etc)

Comment: @juunas have added the scope, using the user-impersonation token.

not 100% confident that thats required with the express setup. when adding the permission, it looks like the AD registration is listed as the app rather than the underlying function app itself